# Reading UDP datagrams from GNSS receiver

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, ip

I am trying to read location data coming from a Airlink MP70 GNSS Gateway into a mock up console app. The GNSS sentences are sent to my computer through ethernet and UDP.

Gateway IP: 192.168.13.31 (GNSS receiver)
Source Port: 17335

Destination IP: 192.168.13.100
Port: 12351

I can see the UDP datagrams with wireshark. The highlighted area is the GNSS data I am trying to extract.

[image]

How would I go receiving this data into a basic console app preferably c# but c++/java python ok too.

Here is what I have so far but I am not seeing any output (it is just the basic code for a UDP client on Microsoft c# site).

```
 private const int listenPort = 12351;

        public static void Main()
        {
            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(listenPort);

            //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.
            // The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source.
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            try
            {

                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received " +
                                          returnData.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                                            " on their port number " +
                                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happened when you ran this?

Comment: Absolutely nothing - I guess its blocking on Receive waiting for data

Comment: Can you verify that by stepping it through in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah its blocking on the Receive method  - created the receivingUdpClient ok

Comment: You program is terminating after reading one message.  Try putting code in the While(true){ } loop.

Comment: The receivingUdpClient.Receive method is a blocking method. The program is just sitting there waiting for data.

Answer (score 0):

My bad - was firewall blocking connection. Thanks from those who helped